# ValueError: Input 0 of layer sequential_34 is incompatible with the layer: expected ndim=3, found ndim=2. Full shape received: (None, 2)

Tags: python, machine-learning, neural-network, lstm

I can't understand why I am getting this error

```
ValueError: Input 0 of layer sequential_41 is incompatible with the layer: expected ndim=3, found ndim=2. Full shape received: (None, 2)
```

This is my code

```
import numpy
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import LSTM, Dense
from keras.layers import Bidirectional
from keras.layers import TimeDistributed
from sklearn.model_selection import KFold, cross_val_score, train_test_split

model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(40, return_sequences=True, input_shape=(2, 1)))
model.add(Dense(20, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(16, activation='sigmoid'))
model.add(Dense(5, activation='tanh'))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(2, activation='softmax'))

model.compile(loss='mean_squared_logarithmic_error', optimizer ='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
#model.fit(trainx, trainy, epochs=10, batch_size=64, verbose=False, shuffle = False)

callback = tf.keras.callbacks.EarlyStopping(monitor='loss', patience=3)
callbacks=[callback]
model.fit(trainx, trainy, epochs=10, batch_size=10, callbacks=[callback])

model.save_weights('LSTMBasic1.h5')
```

```
print(trainx.shape)
print(trainy.shape)
print(testx.shape)
print(testy.shape)

#(3885, 2)  
#(3885,)  
#(686, 2)  
#(686,)
```

Comment: Please post the code as a text not the screenshot.

Comment: what is the error ?

Comment: Please see the title

Comment: Hi @ShehneelKhan, there were no errors during the execution of your code. Please check the [gist](https://colab.sandbox.google.com/gist/synandi/fe1a4c67e6f4f49f11865aeed7d63606/untitled124.ipynb). Thank you!